# Пересечение в typescript

Tags: typescript

У меня есть некий тип `SameType` и есть тип загрузки `type Loading = { isLoading: boolean; skeleton: JSX.Element}`

Мне нужно сделать пересечение таким образом, чтобы у `SameType` если указали поле `isLoading`, то необходимо было бы указать `skeleton`, но при это можно оба этих типа не указывать

Идея в том, что если мы сказали что может быть загрузка, то необходимо подать скелетон

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока писал вопрос, сам придумал ответ

```
SameType & ({ isLoading?: false } | { isLoading: true; skeleton: JSX.Element })
```

Comment: Правильно поставленный вопрос - уже половина ответа :)